# bad user password while encrypting pdf with java

Tags: java, itext, pdfstamper

I am trying to Encrypt pdf file simple with below code

```
public static void securefile(String src, String dest, String passwd, String secure) throws IOException,
                                                                                            DocumentException {
    byte[] USER = "ADEEL".getBytes();
    byte[] OWNER = passwd.getBytes();

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    if (secure == "Y") {
        stamper.setEncryption("ADEEL".getBytes(), passwd.getBytes(), PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING,
                              PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);
    }
    stamper.setFullCompression();
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
```

On call to this method i get exception `bad user password`

Any one can suggest what's happening wrong here

Comment: Is your source pdf probably already encrypted?

Comment: If it's not encrypted already, please provide a stack trace or the PDF file.

Comment: And as a side note: you shouldn't compare Strings by using the "==" operator. Use the equals() method. Or even better, a boolean.

Comment: @Michaël *"shouldn't"* is nicely put. I'd say "mustn't"...

Comment: @mkl "shouldn't" for the off chance that they need to check the references ;)